Weak compositions with no subcomposition adding to (more than) $j$
Here is a solution to a problem from Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics (it's listed as a difficulty 2, so I imagine what I'm about to ask is likely a 2+ or 3-) about the number $\kappa(N,k,j)$ of weak compositions of $N$ into $k$ parts with the restriction that each part has size less than $j$.
I would like to generalize this result so that the size of multiple parts does not equal or exceed $j$ (for example, the number of weak compositions where no two parts add to $j$ or more).
So define $\kappa(N,k,j,b)$ to be the number of weak compositions of $N$ into $k$ parts so that no $b$ of the parts sum to $j$ or greater. When $b=1$ this is just a restriction on the sizes of individual parts, i.e., $\kappa(N,k,j,1) = \kappa(N,k,j)$.
Question: What is a formula for $\kappa(N,k,j,b)$?
I thought there should be a recursive solution that places $j$ objects into $b$ boxes and then places the remaining $N-j$ objects into $k-b$ boxes, but I'm not sure this actually works. I'm not particularly strong in combinatorics, so any help would be appreciated!
A caveat: for large values of $b$, we have $\kappa(N,k,j,b)=0$. That is, there is some minimal $b=b_0$ depending on $N,k,j$ such that $\kappa(N,k,j,b_0)=0$. In fact, writing $N=kq+r$ with $q\geq 1$ and $0\leq r\leq N-1$, an exact formula for this $b_0$ is
$$b_0=\begin{cases}
\left\lceil\frac{j}{q}\right\rceil,~\text{if}~r=0\\\\
\left\lceil\frac{j}{q+1}\right\rceil,~\text{if}~r\neq 0~\text{and}\left\lceil\frac{j}{q+1}\right\rceil\leq r\\\\
r+\left\lceil\frac{j-r(q+1)}{q}\right\rceil,~\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Yes, I intend to discuss weak compositions here.
As to your other question: yes, $b$ is the minimum number such that any weak composition of $N$ into $k$ parts contains $b$ parts that sum to at least $j$. I wrote "boxes" because I'm picturing putting objects into boxes in a stars-and-bars fashion.

The goal is to count weak compositions with the property that no fewer than $b$ parts sum to $j$ or more. For example, how many weak compositions of $N$ into $k$ parts are there where no pair of parts adds to more than $j-1$? What about triples of parts, etc.? At some point, this number becomes zero because of the pigeonhole principle.

I edited the question to match what I think was your intent. Please double-check it to make sure it's what you wanted.

Sure, looks good to me.

Here is a way to obtain the generating function
$$ y=\sum_{N\geq 0}\sum_{k\geq 0}\kappa(N,k,4,2)t^k x^N. $$
From this formula (or from the method itself) you can extract a
formula for $\kappa(N,k,4,2)$. The technique extends to any $j$ and
$b$, but it becomes more complicated as these numbers grow.
For $j=4$ and $b=2$, the following multiset of numbers can appear in a
weak composition. Notation such as $20^r1^s$ means that the weak
composition has one 2, $r$ 0's and $s$ 1's, where $r,s\geq 0$.

$0^r1^s$

$20^r1^s$

$30^r$


In case 1, letting $a=r+s$, the contribution to $y$ is
$$ y_1 = \sum_{a\geq 0} (t+xt)^a = \frac{1}{1-t-xt}. $$
In case 2, again with $a=r+s$, the contribution is
$$ y_2 = \sum_{a\geq 0} tx^2(a+1)(t+xt)^a = \frac{tx^2}
     {(1-t-xt)^2}. $$
In case 3, we get
$$ y_3 = \sum_{r\geq 0}tx^3(r+1)t^r = \frac{tx^3}{(1-t)^2}. $$
Altogether $y=y_1+y_2+y_3$.

Hmm. This certainly will work for specific cases. It seems, however, like there won't be a nice (even recursive) formula for the general case.

@Makenzie: yes, this suggests that there won't be a nice formula in general. But it does show that $\sum_{N\geq 0}\sum_{k\geq 0}\kappa(N,k,j,b)t^k x^N$ is a rational function of $t$ and $x$ for any $j,b$. This can also be seen by a transfer-matrix argument, the basic idea being that once we specify the first $k$ parts of a weak composition, there is a bounded amount of information (namely, the maximum sum of $b-1$ parts so far, which is between $0$ and $(b-1)j$) we need to know to determine the allowed choices for the next part.

@SamHopkins: corrected.

Correction to my previous comment: we need to remember for each $1\leq i\leq b-1$ the maximum sum of $i$ parts in order to update this information when the next part is chosen. But this is still a bounded amount of information.
